# Can't determine cause of MySQL Deadlock

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

It appears to me that (2) TRANSACTION is attempting to acquire a lock it already holds.

Here is the information from "show engine innodb status":

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2016-09-06 14:49:37 2b753b386700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3087948068, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 26 lock struct(s), heap size 6544, 16 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 65912876, OS thread handle 0x2b7558b9c700, query id 59842286726 172.31.7.116 lc update
INSERT INTO LineItem
(LineItemGUID, GuestCheckID, PrimaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier, PLU, BaseCategoryID, BaseItemID, Quantity,
DayPartID, LinePrice, ItemPrice, Tax, Discount, HandKeyedText, Cover, VoidedFlag, RefundedFlag, DateAdded, DateUpdated)
VALUES (upper(uuid()), a_GuestCheckID, a_LineItemPrimaryID, a_LineItemSecondaryID, a_BaseItemPLU, a_MainCategoryID, a_BaseItemID, a_Quantity, a_DayPartID, a_LinePrice, a_ItemPrice, a_Tax, a_DiscountAmount, a_HandKeyedText, a_Cover, a_VoidedFlag, a_RefundedFlag, a_DateAdded, UTC_TIMESTAMP())
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 981521 page no 283632 n bits 824 index `FK_LineItem_GuestCheck` of table `loyaltyconnect`.`lineitem` trx id 3087948068 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 335 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 8000000001fabae9; asc         ;;
1: len 8; hex 80000000088b3379; asc       3y;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3087948052, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
41 lock struct(s), heap size 6544, 57 row lock(s), undo log entries 12
MySQL thread id 65913852, OS thread handle 0x2b753b386700, query id 59842286902 172.31.7.116 lc update
INSERT INTO      LineItem
(LineItemGUID, GuestCheckID, PrimaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier, PLU, BaseCategoryID, BaseItemID, Quantity,
DayPartID, LinePrice, ItemPrice, Tax, Discount, HandKeyedText, Cover, VoidedFlag, RefundedFlag, DateAdded, DateUpdated)
VALUES (upper(uuid()), a_GuestCheckID, a_LineItemPrimaryID, a_LineItemSecondaryID, a_BaseItemPLU, a_MainCategoryID, a_BaseItemID, a_Quantity, a_DayPartID, a_LinePrice, a_ItemPrice, a_Tax, a_DiscountAmount, a_HandKeyedText, a_Cover, a_VoidedFlag, a_RefundedFlag, a_DateAdded, UTC_TIMESTAMP())
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 981521 page no 283632 n bits 824 index `FK_LineItem_GuestCheck` of table `loyaltyconnect`.`lineitem` trx id 3087948052 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 335 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 8000000001fabae9; asc         ;;
1: len 8; hex 80000000088b3379; asc       3y;;

Record lock, heap no 399 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 8000000001fabae6; asc         ;;
1: len 8; hex 80000000088b46ba; asc       F ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 981521 page no 283632 n bits 824 index `FK_LineItem_GuestCheck` of table `loyaltyconnect`.`lineitem` trx id 3087948052 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 335 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 8000000001fabae9; asc         ;;
1: len 8; hex 80000000088b3379; asc       3y;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

and here is the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `lineitem` (
  `LineItemID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LineItemGUID` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GuestCheckID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `PrimaryIdentifier` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SecondaryIdentifier` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DayPartID` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PLU` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BaseCategoryID` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `BaseItemID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL,
  `LinePrice` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `ItemPrice` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `Tax` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `Discount` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `HandKeyedText` varchar(510) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Cover` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `VoidedFlag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `RefundedFlag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Has the entire line item been refunded?',
  `DateAdded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateUpdated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DelFlag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`LineItemID`),
  KEY `FK_LineItem_BaseCategory` (`BaseCategoryID`),
  KEY `FK_LineItem_BaseItem` (`BaseItemID`),
  KEY `FK_LineItem_GuestCheck` (`GuestCheckID`),
  KEY `LineItem_GuestCheck_idx` (`LineItemID`,`GuestCheckID`,`DelFlag`),
  KEY `FK_LineItem_DayPart_idx` (`DayPartID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_LineItem_BaseCategory` FOREIGN KEY (`BaseCategoryID`) REFERENCES `basecategory` (`BaseCategoryID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_LineItem_BaseItem` FOREIGN KEY (`BaseItemID`) REFERENCES `baseitem` (`BaseItemID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_LineItem_DayPart` FOREIGN KEY (`DayPartID`) REFERENCES `daypart` (`DayPartID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_LineItem_GuestCheck` FOREIGN KEY (`GuestCheckID`) REFERENCES `guestcheck` (`GuestCheckID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=143630846 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not like that. Note that (2) already has lock to 981521 page no 283632 n bits 824 index `FK_LineItem_GuestCheck` of table `loyaltyconnect`.`lineitem` trx id 3087948052 lock_mode X locks gap before rec (this is taken for foreign key action NO ACTION that is same as RESTRICT in MySQL). This means that (1) is on lock queue to obtain lock to this same record for foreign key action NO ACTION. Now (2) request locks gap before rec insert intention (this is not same as X lock gap before) for same record, it can't jump ahead in queue because of waiting (1) -> deadlock.

Comment: I'm confused, my use-case is as follows. I've [potentially] got several simultaneous transactions, lets call them A+B. Within each transaction A is inserting several rows into table lineitem, all of which have a single guestcheckid. The same is true for transaction B, but it's using an entirely different guestcheckid. How could they create this deadlock? And is there anything I can change schema-wise to avoid it?